# Break points not removing while attached to process

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

I have a problem removing breakpoints that are set when I attach to a process.

I am attaching to the aspnet_wp process and setting breakpoints. However any breakpoints I remove while debugging are only removed temporarily. when I re-attach the debugger to the process, my breakpoints that I had removed come back again. I have found that the only way to remove the breakpoints, is to remove them when the debugger is not attached to anything. Does anyone know what causes this, and if there is a way to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience that is normal behavior.

[The Mystery of the Reappearing Breakpoints](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=476744)

Comment: Should it be though? Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I have never seen it behave any differently.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening breakpoints window(Debug->Windows->Breakpoints) and deleting the breakpoint from there.